# ReactJS+NodeJS: How to properly redirect user if not logged in?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I have a protected URL - this is how I redirect a user if he's trying to render a page he's not allowed to (this is in a ReactJS component):

```
render() {
  if(!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }
  ...
```

When he's not logged in, he's redirected on the homepage. But in the console, I get these 2 errors:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

The message suggests that I can move the `if`-block to `componentWillMount`? However, isn't `componentWillMount` deprecated?

and the 2nd error message:

```
xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/api/cars 401 (Unauthorized)
```

This message is caused by this block of code in a NodeJS route:

```
router.get('/cars', passport.authenticate('jwt'), function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('logged in');

        Car.find({}).sort('name').exec(function(err, cars) {
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send(JSON.stringify(cars));
        });
    } else {
        // not logged in
        console.log('not logged in');
        //res.send(401);
    }
});
```

If the user is not authenticated, the `401` error is raised in the console and the code inside this route is not executed. Is this the correct behavior? Why there's still the error in the console?

**EDIT:** ReactJS component:

```
class Car extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            errors: {},
            cars: []
        }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        if(!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //console.log('x');
        //console.log(this.props.auth);
        //let self = this;
        axios.get('/api/cars')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({cars: response.data});
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('CAUGHT IT! -> ', err);
                if (err.response.status === 401) {
                    //this.props.history.push('/');
                }
                return err;
            })
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.history.push('/')
        }
        if(nextProps.errors) {
            this.setState({
                errors: nextProps.errors
            });
        }
    }

    handleInputChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const car = {
            name: this.state.name
        }
        console.log(car);
        axios.post('/api/cars/create', car)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log('response.data: ', response.data);
                if(response.data == "success"){
                    console.log('successssss');
                }
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }


    render() { ...
```

Comment: Could add the code where you call the /cars route from your frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Please refrain from asking multiple question in one stack overflow question

---

Error 1:

The error message clearly states that you should not navigate to another page in the render method. But you are doing just that. As the message suggest you could move the code in the componentWillMount livecycle method, but note that this the check will not run on every re-render then.

Error 2:

You seem to be calling this route, which is protected by authentication, while being un-authenticated. Without seeing your client side code I cannot comment further.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you for your answer. I have added the client's code.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick explained about the errors above. 
componentWillMount lifecycle method. is not deprecated as far i know.

I am guessing you are using React Router for your routing needs.
A good example of how to do it properly is [react router private route example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)
It uses Route and Redirect from react-router-dom and creates one special PrivateRoute component. For every route that requires authentication and redirects unauthorised users you’d use this PrivateRoute component instead of just Route component.

you can check authentication and render something else inside the render lifecycle method if needed. But you should not redirect from inside render method.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user like this:

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

...//inside constructor
this.state={
        redirect_path:''//redirect_path is the path you want to redirect the user to
}
```

In componentDidMount check if the user is authorized or not,

If not:

```
this.setState({
           redirect_path:'path_to_redirect_to'   
})
```

In render method:

```
render()
{ //push will add it to the browser history
    if(this.state.redir)
    {
       return(
            <Redirect push to={this.state.redirect_path} />
    }
    else
    {
       //return the page 
    }

 }
```